# Import extension functions s.t. they can be called like member functions?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Let's say I want to make testing easier by cutting down on code duplication and centralising mock creation.

So all of my tests will end up extending

```
public abstract class UnitTestWithGameObjects
{
    private readonly List<GameObject> _createdGameObjects = new List<GameObject>();

    public void DestroyTestGameObjects()
    {
        _createdGameObjects.ForEach(Object.DestroyImmediate);
        _createdGameObjects.Clear();
    }
    
    public GameObject NewGameObject()
    {
        return new GameObject()
            .Also(_createdGameObjects.Add);
    }
}
```

I then add extension functions to that class that create mocks, e.g.

```
public static class TestableTowerCollection
{
    public static ITowerCollection TestTowerCollection(
        this UnitTestWithGameObjects unitTest,
        Properties properties,
        IArCameraManagerWrapper arCameraManagerWrapper = null,
        Vector3? cameraPosition = null,
        IArSessionOriginWrapper arSessionOriginWrapper = null
    )
    {
        IArCameraManagerWrapper cameraManagerWrapper = arCameraManagerWrapper
                                                       ?? unitTest.MockCameraManagerWrapper(cameraPosition);

        IArSessionOriginWrapper sessionOriginWrapper = arSessionOriginWrapper
                                                       ?? unitTest.MockArSessionOriginWrapper();

        return new TowerCollection(properties, cameraManagerWrapper, sessionOriginWrapper);
    }
}
```

where `MockCameraManagerWrapper` and `MockArSessionOriginWrapper` are again extension functions on `UnitTestWithGameObjects` (in different files such as to keep the constructor methods meaningfully bundled).

so in my tests, I can then

```
    public class MyTestUsingTowerCollection : UnitTestWithGameObjects
    {

        private Properties _properties;
        private ITowerCollection _towerCollection;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _properties = new Properties();
            _towerCollection = this.TestTowerCollection(
                _properties,
                cameraPosition: new Vector3(4, 0, -100000)
            );

            ...
        }

        ....
    }
```

But as you will notice, this requires a

```
this.TestTowerCollection(...)
```

invocation, whereas I'd much rather have an implicit `this`:

```
TestTowerCollection(...)
```

like e.g. Kotlin allows (https://ideone.com/wVLEjT)

Can - and if so how - extension functions be imported in a way to allow for this?

Comment: You can't. Extension methods have to be called on an object. If you want to call them on `this`, you have to prefix `this.`

Comment: Adding ````TestTowerCollection```` to ````UnitTestWithGameObjects```` instead of making it extension method?

Comment: Why do you think that makes it look better? For me, it removes context from the code.

Comment: @cly Obviously, as that would turn the extension into a member function. It would, however, also make `UnitTestWithGameObjects` rather large and the member functions hard to find as everything gets mixed together without enforceable structure. I would personally prefer to keep the extension functions separated by "topic" for quicker lookup.

Comment: @DavidG I just feel the `this.` adds nothing but distracting clutter.

Comment: So You want clear code with separated functions but want it to call as simple as possible, right? :)

Comment: @cly Exactly right.

Comment: I would consider refactoring the code to use composition instead of inheritance. If there are no strong reasons to use inheritance, composition usually results in code that is easier to use and understand.

Comment: @JonasH Composition doesn't work here. The intent behind inheriting from `UnitTestWithGameObjects` is that the mock factories will need to (among other things) create new `GameObject` instances that should be destroyed on teardown and therefore need be collected in some way. The `UnitTestWithGameObjects` provides that way, without which we'd need to duplicate it across all our tests.